# Finding best fit curve with unknown power

Tags: regression, gradient-descent, curve-fitting

If I was to build a program to estimate the best curve fit of type $a * x^b$ where a and b are the parameters I'm optimizing, what would be my go to methods?

I know I can use ordinary least squares when b is known. Is there a similar closed form-method for this type of problem, or would I be left with only iterative methods like gradient descent?

Comment: Given that realistically $b$ is discrete and unlikely to be huge you may as well try a standard grid search and pick the best results.

Comment: I realized I limited the problem by calling it a polynomial, so I have edited the title. I meant to imply that b can be any value in $R$

Comment: No problem, happens. :) In that case, yes, our best best is to use an iterative method. Do note though that using gradient descent is probably unnecessarily "simple". As we will have access to the derivatives ($\frac{d}{db}ax^b = ax^b \log(x)$) we can use them directly and get a faster solution with an algorithm like L-BFGS-B.

Comment: And to state the obvious: I hope that $x$ is non-negative. Non-integer exponents of negative numbers can result in complex numbers. :)

Comment: You haven't described the properties of the error term. For example is the error term additive or multiplicative. Are you assuming any particular distributional for for the error term (e.g. normal distribution with mean=0 & constant variance)? What is your optimization criteria? By that I mean what properties should the parameter estimates have? Also if the error term is multiplicative you might be able to apply a log transformation. Without these specifications there is no clear answer.

Comment: I can provide a graphical Python non-liner fitter as an example, if that might be useful.

Comment: What are you assuming about the error term? (or alternatively, but in some cases equivalently, what do you want to optimize?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fitting $\quad y=ax^b$

Since you don't specify the criteria of fitting they are an infinity of different solutions. For example, the solution will not be the same if you are looking for the least mean square error, or the least mean absolute error, or the least mean relative error, or etc.

So if any one of them is sufficient for you, the simplest way is to fit the related logarithmic function. Change of variables :
$$\begin{cases} Y=\ln(y)\\ X=\ln(x) \end{cases}$$
The function to fit is linear : 
$$Y=bX+c$$
Proceed to a linear regression which will give you $b$ and $c$, then $a= e^c$.

If a criteria of fitting is specified, you need to proceed to a non-linear regression : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonlinearLeastSquaresFitting.html

NOTE :

The problem is slightly more complicated if the function to fit includes three parameters instead of two :
$$y=ax^b+c$$
The above change of variables doesn't transform the function to a linear function. A non-linear regression (such as described in the above reference and link) is necessary.

Again if no criteria of fitting is specified, a much simpler method (not iterative, no initial guess) is shown page 17 in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales .